# Cambiar contenido de un section o div a través de un evento onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Hola quiero hacer algo parecido a [esto](http://plnkr.co/edit/IzimSVsstarlFviAm7S7?p=preview) pasandole partes de codigo a mi aside y que mi aside cambie en base a un evento como onclick por ejemplo pero no lo termino de entender el ejemplo realmente no se angularjs si alguno me lo puede explicar o sabe de una forma de hacerlo sin angularjs. Saludos

PD: Lamento hacer otra vez la publicacion pero realmente necesito la ayuda trate de explicarme de la forma mas concisa que pude esta vez

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(ShowTime, 1000);
    setInterval(MostrarDiaLetras, 1000);
});

function ShowTime() {
    
    var TheDate = new Date();
    
    var TheHour = TheDate.getHours();
    var TheMinutes = TheDate.getMinutes();

    TheMinutes = (TheMinutes < 10) ? "0" + TheMinutes :  TheMinutes;
    
    var TheTime = TheHour + ":" +TheMinutes;
    
    $('#TheDate').html(TheTime);     
}

function MostrarDiaLetras() {
    
    var date = new Date();
    
    var dia = date.getDay();
    var mes = date.getMonth();
    var diaMes= date.getDate();
  var diaLetras;
  var mesLetras;

    diaLetras = (dia == 0) ? "Domingo"  :  diaLetras;
    diaLetras = (dia == 1) ? "Lunes"  :  diaLetras;
    diaLetras = (dia == 2) ? "Martes"  :  diaLetras;
    diaLetras = (dia == 3) ? "Miercoles"  :  diaLetras;
    diaLetras = (dia == 4) ? "Jueves"  :  diaLetras;
    diaLetras = (dia == 5) ? "Viernes"  :  diaLetras;
    diaLetras = (dia == 6) ? "Sabado"  :  diaLetras;
  
  mesLetras=(mes == 0) ? "Enero"  :  mesLetras;
  mesLetras=(mes == 1) ? "Febrero"  :  mesLetras;
  mesLetras=(mes == 2) ? "Marzo"  :  mesLetras;
  mesLetras=(mes == 3) ? "Abril"  :  mesLetras;
  mesLetras=(mes == 4) ? "Mayo"  :  mesLetras;
  mesLetras=(mes == 5) ? "Junio"  :  mesLetras;
  mesLetras=(mes == 6) ? "Julio"  :  mesLetras;
  mesLetras=(mes == 7) ? "Agosto"  :  mesLetras;
  mesLetras=(mes == 8) ? "Septiembre"  :  mesLetras;
  mesLetras=(mes == 9) ? "Octubre"  :  mesLetras;
  mesLetras=(mes == 10) ? "Noviembre"  :  mesLetras;
  mesLetras=(mes == 11) ? "Diciembre"  :  mesLetras;


    var Fecha = diaLetras+"<br/>" +diaMes +" "+ mesLetras;
    $('#DiaLetras').html(Fecha);     
}
```

```css
html{
 font-family: sans-serif
}

main {
 float: left;
 width: 70%;
}

aside{
 float: right;
 width: 30%;
}

/*  Cambio tamaño glyphi*/
header .glyphicon {
    font-size: 25px;
}

/*  Cambio color bordes del menu*/
.navbar-default{
 border-bottom-width: 2px;
 border-bottom-color: #F49D51;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/*  Cambio de color a active del menu*/

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #F49D51;
}

/*  Dropdown tamaño etc */

.navbar-login
{
    width: 305px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-login-session
{
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.icon-size
{
    font-size: 87px;
}

.navbar-right{
 margin-right: 0px;
}

/*  --------- */
.sub-top{
 padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
 height: 46px;
 background-color: #444444;
}

main .sub-top{
 padding-bottom: 0px;
}

aside .sub-top{
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
 border-left-color: #3a3a3a;
}

.nav-tabs{
 border-bottom: none;
}

.nav-tabs>li{
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a{
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: #444444;
 border: none;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a:hover,
.nav-tabs>li>a:focus{
 color:#F49D51;
 background-color: #444444;
 border: none;
}



.nav-tabs>li.active>a, 
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, 
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: #666666;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 border: 0px none;
}

.desc{
 display: block;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 10px 18px;
}

main .desc{
 background-color: #666666;

}

aside .desc{
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
 border-left-color: #d5d5d5;
}

.titlecat{
 float: left;
 margin:0px;
 font-size: 17px;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold; 
 padding-top: 5px;
 width: 70%
}

.desc .btn-default{
 color:#fff;
 background-color: #444444;
 border-style: none;
 float: right;


}


.btn-default:active:hover,
.btn-default.active:hover,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:active:focus,
.btn-default.active:focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default:active.focus,
.btn-default.active.focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
}

.Principalside{
 background-color: #f6f6f6;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
 border-left-color: #d5d5d5;
 height: 640px;
}

.glyphicon-plus {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.table{
 width:90%;
 float:left;
}

#inputBuscar{
 width:40%;
 float:left;
 margin-left: 28%;
}

.col-lg-offset-1{
 margin-left: 5%;
}

.row{
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.date{
 display: block;
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 0px 20px 0px 5px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 color: #666666;
}

.fecha{
 display: block;
 font-size: 11px;
 padding-top: 16px;
 color: #666666;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.table tbody tr:hover{
 background-color: #ffeebb;
 border: 1px 0px solid #ffcc66;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Trabajo Cuatrimestral OO2</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/design.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/search.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/date.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/stidges/jquery-searchable/master/dist/jquery.searchable-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="top-left">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../imgs/logo.jpg" width="200" height="35"></a></li>
            <li id="restaurant">
              <a href="../restaurant/salon.html" title="Restaurant">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li id="ventas">
             <a href="#productos/" title="Ventas">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
             </a>
            </li>
            <li class="active" id="productos">
             <a href="../productos/productos.html" title="Productos">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-apple" aria-hidden="true"></span>
             </a>
            </li>
            <li id="client">
             <a href="#productos/" title="Clientes">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
             </a>
            </li>
            <li id="report">
             <a href="#productos/" title="Reportes">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span>
             </a>
            </li>
            <li id="config">
             <a href="#productos/" title="Configuración">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
             </a>
            </li>

          </ul>
         </div>
   <div class="top-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li>
      <div id="DiaLetras" class="fecha"></div>
     </li>
    
     <li>
      <div id="TheDate" class="date"></div>
     </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> 
                  <strong>Nombre</strong>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <div class="navbar-login">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <p class="text-center">
                          <img src="../imgs/foto-carnet.jpg" width="100" height="100">
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <p class="text-left"><strong>Nombre Apellido</strong></p>
                        <p class="text-left small">correoElectronico@email.com</p>
                        <p class="text-left">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm">Actualizar Datos</a>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <div class="navbar-login navbar-login-session">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <p>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Cerrar Sesion</a>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <main>
  <section class="sub-top">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="productos.html">Productos</a></li>
            <li><a href="Ingredientes.html">Ingredientes</a></li>
            <li><a href="Platos.html">Platos</a></li>
            <li><a href="Menus.html">Menus</a></li>
            <li><a href="Viandas.html">Viandas</a></li>
            <li><a href="Rubro.html">Rubro</a></li>
            <li><a href="Subrubro.html">Subrubro</a></li>
          </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="desc">
   <h1 class="titlecat">
    <span>PRODUCTOS</span>
   </h1>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Nuevo Producto
   </button>

  </section>
  <section >
   <div class="table-main">
    <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-3" id="inputBuscar">
                  <input type="search" id="search" value class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar producto">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-lg-offset-1">
                  <table class="table" id="table">
                      <thead class="thead-inverse">
                          <tr>
                              <th>Cod.</th>
                              <th>Producto</th>
                              <th>Precio</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <td>20</td>
                              <td>Salsa</td>
                              <td>25</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>13</td>
                              <td>PrePizza</td>
                              <td>50</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>11</td>
                              <td>Muzarella</td>
                              <td>40</td>
                          </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
              </div>
          </div>
         </div> 
  </section>
 </main>
 <aside>
  <section class="sub-top">
  </section>
  <section class="desc">
   <h1 class="titlecat">
    <span></span>
   </h1>
  </section>
  <section class="Principalside">

  </section>
 </aside>
</body>
</html>
```

Quiero que el contenido la clase PrincipalSide cambie en base a un evento onclick de la tabla

Comment: Dario, buenas, para poder brindar ayuda, deberíamos tener el código que estás usando, y la descripción del error que te ha llevado a hacer la pregunta. En caso de que tu problema sea de conocimiento en cuanto a algo en particular, especifica la linea que genera la confusión y porqué. Saludos

Comment: Es que en mi anterior pregunta puse todo y me dijieron que sea mas conciso mil disculpas ahi esta editado

Comment: No veo rastros de [tag:angularjs], solo de [tag:jquery].

Comment: El código de angularjs en el link que compartiste está haciendo uso de algo llamado routing usando la librería `ui-router` lo cual es mucho más complejo de lo que quieres lograr

Comment: No estoy usando angularjs porque no se el lenguaje solo googlie para ver si se podía hacer lo que quería y encontré eso

Answer (score 2):

Obtén el contenido que quieres agregar en una variable `Javascript`, luego agrégalo a la sección con el siguiente código:

```js
var texto;
texto = "Hola Mundo";
function change(){
  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = texto;
}
```

```html
<div id='mydiv'>TEXTO QUE VA A CAMBIAR</div>
<br/>
<input type='button' onclick='change()' value='cambiar valor'>
```

Answer (score 0):

En esta respuesta brindo una solución de propósito general en cuanto a cambiar el contenido de un elemento DOM ya sea un `div` u otro implementando un sistema sencillo de componentes usando jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  // El objeto components actua como un diccionario de componentes
  // Cada componente tiene dos propiedades:
  // - template: Es el html a ser renderizado.
  // - controller: Son las operaciones a ser realizadas sobre el
  //               html renderizado, el argumento "element" hace
  //               referencia al elemento DOM contenedor del html
  //               renderizado.
  // NOTA: se está usando la notación de "template literals" de ES2015
  // para evitar concatenar strings, así que puede que navegadores
  // extremadamente antiguos no puedan soportar este ejemplo.
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
  var components = {
    o1: {
      template:`
        <div>
          <span>Contenido de la opción 1</span>
        </div>
      `,
      controller: function (element) {
        element.find('span').css('color', 'red');
      }
    },
    o2: {
      template: `
        <div>
          <h1>Opción 2</h1>
          <span>Contenido de la opción 2</span>
        </div>
      `,
      controller: function (element) {
        element.find('h1').css('color', 'blue');
      }
    },
    o3: {
      template: `
        <div>
          <h2>Opción 3</h2>
          <pre>Contenido de la opción 2</pre>
        </div>
      `,
      controller: function (element) {
        element.find('pre').css('color', 'green');
      }
    }
  };
  
  // Renderiza el html de cada componente y ejecuta el controlador
  // de este pasando el elemento contenedor como argumento.
  function renderComponent(element, componentName) {
    var component = components[componentName];
    element.html(component.template);
    component.controller(element);
  }
  
  // Un selector que busca todos los links y les asigna un click
  // listener que hace el cambio de componente sobre el elemento
  // usando el nombre del atributo "id" como llave del diccionario
  // de componentes.
  $('li.opcion a').click(function () {
  
    var aside = $('#mi-aside');
    // this hace referencia al elemento encontrado
    // this.id hace referncia al atributo "id"
    renderComponent(aside, this.id);
  });
});
```

```css
/* Los links sin el atributo href pierden el cursor,
 * aquí se está forzando a que tengan cursor.
 */
a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="opcion"><a id="o1">Opcion 1</a></li>
  <li class="opcion"><a id="o2">Opcion 2</a></li>
  <li class="opcion"><a id="o3">Opcion 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="mi-aside"></div>
```

Comment: Es mejor esperar a que el OP aclare qué es lo que está usando; porque ha etiquetado su pregunta con [tag:angularjs], aunque no veo rastro de él. Si resulta que usa [tag:angularjs] la respuesta no serviría mucho ya que este contiene su propio sistema de routing.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Gracias, no me percaté lo de las etiquetas

Comment: es lo que quiero que haga pero desde ese template yo puedo poner codigo jsp porque a la ahora de editar algo traeria los datos de java? y puse la etiqueta por el ejemplo que les pegue pero ahi la quito asi queda mas claro

Comment: Si tu idea es que cambie el contenido de un div sin recargar la página entonces tu servidor debería ser capaz de manejar llamadas en [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) para traer los datos requeridos hasta el cliente y usar [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com) u otra librería para renderizar templates de html con dichos datos obtenidos

Comment: si te explico este proyecto es para la universidad la idea seria usar ajax de la sig manera por ejem:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#consultar').click(function () {
var dni = $('#dni').val();
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "MostrarClienteJSP",
data: { dni: dni },
async: false
}).done(function (data) {
$("#responsecliente").html(data);
})
});
});
</script>

a diferencia del ejemplo yo tomaria el cod Producto de la fila de la tabla y invocar al controlador que traiga todos los datos de ese producto y eso pasarlo a una vista en jsp

Comment: Pienso que es tema para otra pregunta especificando las etiquetas JSP y Ajax y quitando estrictamente todo lo relacionado con AngularJS, no voy a ahondar más en el tema que no sea lo que se ha especificado en la pregunta