# ¿Como cambiar de pagina sin cambiar el url?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Me dejaron hacer hacer una pagina que al momento de dar clic en cualquier sección del menú me cargue todo lo que este en esa sección sin cambiar de url.

Comment: Pues a darle duro con ajax

Comment: [Puedes leer la segunda respuesta de esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80574/cambiar-contenido-de-un-section-o-div-a-través-de-un-evento-onclick)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [como cargar varias paginas en la misma pagina](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130552/como-cargar-varias-paginas-en-la-misma-pagina)

Comment: Esto normalmente se llama `single-page application`, existen múltiples librerias y framework que te ayudan a desarrollar este tipo de aplicaciones web.

Comment: Esta pregunta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Aunque el tema es pertinente e interesante para el sitio, tal y como está redactada es muy amplia. Por favor, edítala para añadir más detalles: una descripción mejor del problema, de lo que hayas intentado y de los errores/dificultades que te estés encontrando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos posibilidades:

1. Usar AJAX
2. iFrame

Para usar AJAX, simplemente haz la llamada AJAX en el evento javascript deseado contra el PHP que devuelve los datos y los muestras en el HTML dinámicamente. Puedes mirar cómo en esta otra respuesta [Adaptar archivo .PHP a .HTML para poder incrustar Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126476/adaptar-archivo-php-a-html-para-poder-incrustar-javascript/131413#131413)

Para el iFrame ya te ha respondido Humberto

Edito: Hay una tercera opción, los tabs, como dice Anton y puede que haya más.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te refieres a un `<iframe src="URL"></iframe>` Este te permite agregar un documento diferente pero en el mismo documento

Answer (score 1):

Esto puedes lograrlo naturalmente con unos tabs de navegación. HTML+CSS
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp